# my unconfirmed transactions hold for over 1 day

Tags: wallet, unconfirmed-transactions, buy-bitcoins

I have following 2 unconfirmed bitcoin incoming transaction for one day, can you please advise how to speed up?

1Eg8thYVMBTpXg78FQo2sXhxeFdZWB9DjN

1D3grbjFXZWUp1wCApLTHQ9GAxsyyAawkU

Answer (score 0):

Your question will be closed as duplicate which may or may not help you, if you really did those transactions associated with addresses mentioned in the question. Try doing the following in future:

1. Use RBF (Replace by Fee)
2. Use fee rate more than others if transaction is urgent. Check multiple websites: https://mempool.space https://btc.bitaps.com https://mempool.observer